# get value from mysql database using month no and week no

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to retrieve the records from the table using month no and week no 
for example I have a table

```
CustomerID  CustomerName    date(data type date) 
1            sam            2016-06-1
2            dam            2016-06-2
3            kam            2016-06-8
4            ram            2016-06-9
4            ram            2016-07-8  

how can i retrieve the month no 6 and week no 1 records 

after the select query expected result is

CustomerID  CustomerName    date
1            sam            2016-06-1
2            dam            2016-06-2

it will give 2 records because date 1 and 2 fall under first week
```

if question is not clear please reply 
thanks !

Comment: @  Strawberry week is the no of week like june 2016 having 5 weeks when we start day from sunday. Actually I am counting no of week from PHP and pass it to mysql query

Comment: You mean Sunday 29th May?

Comment: Look into some semblance of a standard like the one given in mysql for week number in a year. There are multiple `modes` that can be used for it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `month` and `week` functions. [Documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week).

```
select * from table where month(`date`) = 6 and week(`date`) = 1
```

Comment: It is worked with month function but not working in the case of week even in the case of weekday().

Comment: The op wants week of month, not week of year